# Polygon pattern analysis -> point pattern analysis?

Tags: r, point-process

Is it correct to convert polygons to points in order to do a point pattern analysis ?

I have a set of polygons that tend to be clustered around roads in a study area. I just want to show this fact.
The polygons are of different sizes. Converting them to centroids, marked with their own area, or to multiple points, doesn't seem relevant to me.

Could you suggest any other options ?

[image]